# How to show small values with large values in google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

You can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emigort/7v4sqmo2/)

In the year 2004 I have values of 1000, and in the other years I have large values, for that reason in the scale the chart doesn't seems able to rendered, what can I do to show those values. I was reading [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/08/20/charts-with-small-and-large-values/). Is there a way to do something like that in google chart?

Here is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      1000],
    ['2005',  1170000,      460000],
    ['2006',  660000,       1120000],
    ['2007',  1030000,      540000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The chart

[image]

Comment: There is a logScale option, but still wouldn´t work for the value 1

Comment: @juvian I change the values to 1000 and added 3 zeros to the other numbers, could comment your idea on what you were trying

Comment: `vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, logScale:true}`

Comment: No problem, good luck with proyect

Comment: @juvian you should post as an answer, I search in all stackoverflow and I didn't find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Chart´s axis have an option to set scale to logarithm, which fits better for big differences between lowest and highest values. Note that all values must be positive and if the data value is 1, it won´t show as logharithm scale starts at 1 or higher. To change it, use:

```
vAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, logScale:true}
```

You can find the documentation in configuration options section:

[Google Chart Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options)